# How do I setup static mount via /etc/fstab for Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos

I am mounting a storj node on my centos 7 server. In one of the steps it asks me that you must static mount via / etc / fstab.
Listening to the documentation.

First, run the following command and find the name of the hard drive you wish to use (for example sda2)

```
lsblk
NAME MAJ: MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8: 0 0 1,8T 0 disk
sda1 8: 1 0 9.8G 0 part /
sda2 8: 2 0 511M 0 part [SWAP]
sda3 8: 3 0 1,8T 0 part / home
```

Once you find it, we will now get the Unique ID (UUID) of the hard drive

```
lsblk -d -fs / dev / <location (example: sda2)>
```

Copy the UUID, as well as the FSTYPE. We’ll need that later.

Here I do not know how to continue I do not know how to use that command with the data obtained in the first

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add following data to `/etc/fstab:`

```
UUID="xxx"  "my_mount_directory" "fstype" defaults 0 0
```

after creating the directory "my_mount_directory".

For example for a ext4 file system that needs to be available in /mnt/myfs

```
$ mkdir /mnt/myfs
```

Add in /etc/fstab:

```
 UUID="3b9668a3-17df-4e1e-99c2-5dcb0fd46778"    /mnt/myfs ext4 defaults 0 0
```

And run:

```
$ mount /mnt/myfs
```

Comment: The help is appreciated, it is not exactly as explained in the storj documentation but I suppose it will be a different method of obtaining the same result. :)